# annotationView didChangeDragState being fired multiple times

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit, mkannotation

I've got a draggable annotation in IOS4 mapkit, and I'm trying to call an event when the annotation is dragged to a new position.

my code currently looks like:

```
   - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView  annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView 
    didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState 
{
    if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D droppedAt = annotationView.annotation.coordinate;
        NSLog(@"dropped at %f,%f", droppedAt.latitude, droppedAt.longitude);

        //update the annotation
        //see if its an information annotation
        if ([annotationView.annotation isKindOfClass:[InfoAnnotation class]]) {
            NSLog(@"Info annotation updating..");
            InfoAnnotation* userAnnotation = ((InfoAnnotation *)annotationView.annotation);
            [userAnnotation updateLocationWithServerForConvoy: self.title];
        }

    }
}
```

the code simply logs the update and then tells the annotation to send its update to my server, which is a custom method.

This method seems to be getting fired multiple times, see the log here:

```
2011-06-15 01:12:39.347 Convoy[1699:207] dropped at 37.340206,-122.027550
2011-06-15 01:12:39.347 Convoy[1699:207] Info annotation updating..
2011-06-15 01:12:39.658 Convoy[1699:207] dropped at 37.340206,-122.027550
2011-06-15 01:12:39.659 Convoy[1699:207] Info annotation updating..
2011-06-15 01:12:39.957 Convoy[1699:207] dropped at 37.340206,-122.027550
2011-06-15 01:12:39.958 Convoy[1699:207] Info annotation updating..


2011-06-15 01:12:43.415 Convoy[1699:207] dropped at 37.339251,-122.026691
2011-06-15 01:12:43.416 Convoy[1699:207] Info annotation updating..
2011-06-15 01:12:43.713 Convoy[1699:207] dropped at 37.339251,-122.026691
2011-06-15 01:12:43.713 Convoy[1699:207] Info annotation updating..
2011-06-15 01:12:44.006 Convoy[1699:207] dropped at 37.339251,-122.026691
2011-06-15 01:12:44.006 Convoy[1699:207] Info annotation updating..
2011-06-15 01:12:44.297 Convoy[1699:207] dropped at 37.339251,-122.026691
2011-06-15 01:12:44.297 Convoy[1699:207] Info annotation updating..


2011-06-15 01:12:54.825 Convoy[1699:207] dropped at 37.337135,-122.025833
2011-06-15 01:12:54.825 Convoy[1699:207] Info annotation updating..
2011-06-15 01:12:55.150 Convoy[1699:207] dropped at 37.337135,-122.025833
2011-06-15 01:12:55.150 Convoy[1699:207] Info annotation updating..
2011-06-15 01:12:55.475 Convoy[1699:207] dropped at 37.337135,-122.025833
2011-06-15 01:12:55.476 Convoy[1699:207] Info annotation updating..
2011-06-15 01:12:55.771 Convoy[1699:207] dropped at 37.337135,-122.025833
2011-06-15 01:12:55.772 Convoy[1699:207] Info annotation updating..
2011-06-15 01:12:56.070 Convoy[1699:207] dropped at 37.337135,-122.025833
2011-06-15 01:12:56.070 Convoy[1699:207] Info annotation updating..
```

Each time I drag it (ie in the gaps) it seems to add 1 to the amount of times it's called. Can anyone give me any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: Looks like we are the only people with this problem. I have exactly the same behaviour as you describe.
What I noticed is that when the dragged annotation is MKPinAnnotationView, it works fine, but if your annotation is a MKAnnotationView the problem occurs. Looks very much like a bug in the ios.
I will open one at apple.
Maybe you will want to do that as well to get more pressure?

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is still wondering - you have to set the MKAnnotationView drag state to 
`MKAnnotationViewDragStateNone`.

So the code would be:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState
{
  if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding)
  {
    /* ... */
    [annotationView setDragState:MKAnnotationViewDragStateNone];
    // If you are animating - move the above into the completion block
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That does seem odd. Have you thought about simply hooking in to your annotation's setCoordinate method instead? MapKit calls this once whenever an MKMapAnnotation is moved by dragging.