# Why AnnotationView didChangeDragState have called many times?

Tags: ios, xcode, android-mapview

I'm new to iOS. I've used code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3999583/1572234

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView 
didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState 
fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState 
{
if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding)
   {
    NSLog(@"didChangeDragState");
   }
}

- (void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView
{
if ([[annotationView.annotation title] isEqualToString:@"2nd"]||[[annotationView.annotation title] isEqualToString:@"3rd"])
   {
    NSLog(@"didSelectAnnotationView");
   }
}
```

But after I've tried to drag pin for three times, I saw this in my debug area:

```
 2012-08-05 14:47:06.962 TestApp[1692:11603] didSelectAnnotationView
 2012-08-05 14:47:11.825 TestApp[1692:11603] didChangeDragState
 2012-08-05 14:47:16.269 TestApp[1692:11603] didSelectAnnotationView
 2012-08-05 14:47:20.205 TestApp[1692:11603] didChangeDragState
 2012-08-05 14:47:20.207 TestApp[1692:11603] didChangeDragState
 2012-08-05 14:47:24.033 TestApp[1692:11603] didSelectAnnotationView
 2012-08-05 14:47:26.811 TestApp[1692:11603] didChangeDragState
 2012-08-05 14:47:26.814 TestApp[1692:11603] didChangeDragState
 2012-08-05 14:47:26.816 TestApp[1692:11603] didChangeDragState
```

I need only one call of NSLog(@"didChangeDragState"), every time i've dragged the pin , what am I missing? Help plz.

Comment: The Ending state should only happen once when the pin is dropped but the pin could go through multiple states before then.  Are you sure the log messages are from the code posted?  Try this: `NSLog(@"didChangeDragState, title=%@, os=%d, ns=%d", annotationView.annotation.title, oldState, newState);` and `ns=4` should only appear when the pin is dropped.

Comment: possible duplicate of [annotationView didChangeDragState being fired multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345888/annotationview-didchangedragstate-being-fired-multiple-times)

Answer (score 1):

it's an old bug in ios. I reported that to apple more than a year ago, but they say they cant reproduce it...
I added a fix of my own:

```
 if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding)
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D droppedAt = annotationView.annotation.coordinate;
    //drmap1 and drmap2 initialized to 0 before

    double d1=drmap1-droppedAt.latitude;
    double d2=drmap2-droppedAt.longitude;
    if(d1<0.000001&&d1>=-0.000001&&d2<0.000001&&d2>=-0.000001) return; //V1.2a fix a bug in ios

    drmap1=droppedAt.latitude;
    drmap2=droppedAt.longitude;
```